# Angular frontend isAuthenticated false using Passport in Sails

Tags: angularjs, sails.js, passport.js

I'm trying to use Sails as a server side only and Angular frontend in a different server - I already have a Sails/Jade running perfectly.

To start using AngularJS as frontend I have enable CORS. After that, I start to login successfully (using Passport). But now when I try to access a private area req.isAuthenticated() aways returns false.

The interesting thing is if I open the Sails/Jade (backend + frontend), connect and then try to use my Angular version (fronend), the `req.isAuthenticated()` return true.

Investigating my problem I saw that passport call `serializeUser()` in my Angular login, but don't call `deserializeUser()` when I try to access my private area.

In env/development.js

```
cors = {
  allRoutes: true,
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
  methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD'
};
```

Client HTML:

```
<form name="loginForm" ng-submit="private()">
   <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Access">
</form>
```

My angular call:

```
function accessPrivateArea() {
  return $http({
     url: url,
     type: backendUrl + "private",
     withCredentials: true
  });
}
```

Comment: I think you should add `'origin': '*'` to the config.

Comment: changed my configuration without success.